# How to Increase the MaxArrayLength in a WCF web.config - for uploading large files

Tags: asp.net

I have dig all around the net for two days about it, and I can't make my asp.net web site to upload files bigger then 16Kb
I'm using fileUploader,wcf, and I have service reference in the client.
when I upload file in 30KB size it asked me to increase the MaxArrayLength.

> The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   2
>    MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 205847.

and it's just what I did, but it keeps complaining about this.

if I upload file in 1MB size, I get error 400.

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

please help

the client app.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding> 

    <binding name="streamingBinding"
              transferMode="Streamed"/>


    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBLServer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>

  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8888/BLService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBLServer" contract="WSRef.IBLServer"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IBLServer" />
</client>
```

the WCF web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="BLServer.BackEndBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="05:05:00" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"
       maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streamingBinding"
              transferMode="Streamed"/>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBLServer"
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
          <readerQuotas
              maxDepth="64"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647"
             maxBytesPerRead="4096"
             maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="BLServer.BackEndBehavior" name="WSRef.BackEnd">
       <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBLServer"
              contract="WSRef.IBLServer" />

  </service>


  <service name="StreamingService.Upload">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="streamingBinding"
              contract="StreamingService.IUpload"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

files <16 KB are uploaded successfully.

can you please find out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Ok, I see you are doing it already... Are you sure yopu are mapping the bindings correctly. Check the first post below, they had a problem with the mapping of the binding.

Check these out:

[Maximum array length quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/maximum-array-length-quota)

[WCF service The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068076/wcf-service-the-maximum-array-length-quota-16384-has-been-exceeded)

[Changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035600/changing-the-maxarraylength-property-on-the-xmldictionaryreaderquotas-object-used)

[How to handle large file uploads via WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935040/how-to-handle-large-file-uploads-via-wcf)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I looked at thos links, but the problem still exist.

Comment: OK, I had one mistake, I was thinking my client is the one that call to the WS reference instance. so the web.config where I changed the "maxArrayLength" wasn't the right one. but even now, when I think my client is the ASP.NET proj, the error still appears "The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded ". I'm sure I did that good this time, because when I decrease the value - maxArrayLength="100" my site show the same error, with the value "100", but when I increase it larger then 16384, it still complains that the current maxArrayLength is 16384, and that I need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for hours.  Finally, I realized that I was using a config file transform, and my `maxArrayLength` kept getting overwritten by the transform.  Time for some caffeine.